# Exception NSException * "-[EggTimer.ViewController hardness:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1552060a0" 0x0000600001722250

Tags: ios, swift

?????Please help this code is showing the the error->

> Exception NSException * "-[EggTimer.ViewController hardness:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1552060a0" 0x0000600001722250

this is the error and I don’t know the solution.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let eggTimes = ["Soft" : 5, "Medium" : 7, "Hard" : 12]

    
    
    @IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let hardness = sender.currentTitle!
        let result = eggTimes[hardness]!
        print(result)
        
    }
    
        
}
```

its to print the times on which the egg will be boiled as soft(5min), medium(7min), hard(12min).
(If the image helps)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jckIL.png)

Comment: Check the `touchUpInside` event, which is mapping with @IBAction.

Comment: You did rename the method from `hardness(_:)` to `hardnessSelected(_:)`, but didn"t undo the IBAction link in the Storyboard. Remove it and recreate it with the new method.